# Where is the log updated for WAR file runs

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

When I run a project with Run-As, the Console in eclipse shows the errors exceptions for the WAR file run. But when I export the WAR file and upload to the server, where is the log updated ?

Edit : I am using Apache 7 Tomcat

Comment: It is by default in catalina.out file under logs folder in your tomcat,If you havent configured logs

Answer (score 0):

You can find the log in text file under folder:

```
\apache-tomcat-7.X.XX\logs\
```